# Unable to create object of class inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having problem creating an object of another class in fragment.  My code is

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutinflater,
        ViewGroup viewgroup, Bundle bundle) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    (/*ERROR LINE*/)Database info = new Database(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
    return layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.sqlview, viewgroup, false);
}
```

But it is telling me to modify the constructor in the database class which has Context as argument.
Please help.

Comment: you might have an error on following line too : **(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView3);**.  did this textview is on `sqlview`?

Comment: Yes it is. I dont have error over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Merlevede answer for your question, but after running this application you must get **NullPointerException** error on :

```
tv.setText(data);
```

because `tv` is `null`

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

`textView3` is on `sqlview`. so you must change your code with following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutinflater,
        ViewGroup viewgroup, Bundle bundle) {
    View v = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.sqlview, viewgroup, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    Database info = new Database(getActivity());
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Spot on!! I didnt quite understand why tv is null.

Comment: you put `textView3` on `sqlview` but you want access that with `getActivity()` method, `getActivity` return your activity layout that is some other layout, you need this layout for access to `textView3` so you need first declare your view and use `v.findViewById()`

Comment: i don't know where you exactly can read this, but when you inflate other layout and want to work with widget on that layout you must do like this, like on Custom adapter and many other place, i hope you get me

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
Database info = new Database(getActivity());
```

`getActivity()` returns the activity associated with the fragment, and since `Activity` inherits from `Context` you can use it as the parameter for you constructor.

Comment: It is giving me a NPE

Answer (score 0):

You have to add constructor in Database.java

```
class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, "Your Database Name", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // write you create table query here.
    }


    // other method to get data...



}
```

This will resolve your constructor issue.